# jQuery: can I traverse within the not() method

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I want to address all other DOM elements with a particular class in all containers except the current one. Can I traverse to siblings within the `not` method?

Example code structure (all divs have some content which is left out here):

```
<div class="x">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
<div class="y">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
<div class="z">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```

*EDIT (after already having got the right answer...): (Sorry, i made a mistake in my question when transferring my real situation to this example structure):*

When clicking on the second element with class `.b` (i.e. selector `$('.y .b')`, I would like to set (actually *reset*) the `color` for class `.d` in the two other elements, i.e. selectors `$('.x .d')` and `$('.z .d')`. In the real situation there are much more elements and I would like to avoid the too long (and all different) selectors I otherwise have to use.

So I am thinking of something like

```
 $('.b').click(function(){
    $('.d').not(siblings()).css('backgroundColor', '#d8a');
  })
```

But that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: you are calling `siblings()`, not the `$().siblings()`

Comment: I got confused. ok what do you want to do when you are clicking over `$(".x .b")`?

Comment: why can't you just do this: `$('.b').css('backgroundColor', '#d8a');` ? This won't affect its siblings

Comment: The "not sibling" of `.b` is `.b`. Are you sure you don't just want the siblings()? Check out the example in the docs: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: @Johannes, well it's not really the answer... answer might be something like `$('.b').not($(this).siblings())...` but not sure without seeing the context

Comment: @smerny Yes, that's what I meant / found with your help! It works now...

Comment: What is `this`? What is being clicked?

Comment: sorry everybody for the confusion - see my edited question and the edit-note in there. I already got the answer which led me to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you were trying to call a stand-alone `siblings()` function (by that, I mean not a function on a jQuery object), you probably would have seen a reference error in your js console that `siblings` is not defined.

To select all of `.d` minus the siblings of the current element, you could do something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xmbvLv1/)

```
$('.d').not($(this).siblings()).css('backgroundColor', '#d8a');
```

This looks like exactly what you were trying to do with your js, and will select **all** of `.d` on the entire page **except** the direct siblings of the target element.

---

If your actual DOM is as simple as the example, you probably only want to select the parent's sibling's `.d` children. Which could be done like..

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children('.d').css('backgroundColor', '#d8a');
```

Comment: depends on the actual dom and where this js is placed

Comment: @smerny Again, sorry for the confusion, but I am clicking `.b` for selecting all `.d`s *except* the one which is a sibling of the `.b` i am clicking.

Comment: @smerny, it's not only the click function: inside the `not()` parenthesis I added `$(this)` before `.siblings()` ,which was the crucial detail that was missing.

Comment: @smerny in the question, it's clicking `.b` for selecting `.d` in the other parent containers, not the other way round. If you want to edit your answer again, I'll be happy to delete mine.

Comment: @smerny your answer still contained this: "To select all of .d minus the siblings of the current element" - I changed that to `.b` and will delete my answer now. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @Johannes, ah, I see.